# Is there a good place to discuss Test Driven Development?

Tags: tdd

I've just signed up for the Google group entitled Test Driven Development but it's only had 3 posts in 2010 and seems to be littered with spam.

Does anyone know of a good TDD focussed place to ask those general perhaps 'subjective' questions which might not be welcomed on SO?

Comment: @Andrew, I fear the temptation to go off topic might be too great

Comment: It's trivial to avoid "subjective" questions on SO.  Avoid providing your opinions -- avoid questions like "What's the alternative to TDD"? (Implicitly, your opinion is that you don't like it.)  Or questions like "Since TDD is obviously so much more work, what's the point?"  (Explicitly, your opinion is that you think it's somehow more work.)  It's easy to eliminate your opinion and ask non-subjective, non-argumentative questions.  Try it.

Comment: @S.Lott you mean I should refactor my questions to remove needless subjectivity?

Comment: @panamack: "needless subjectivity"?  No.  All subjectivity.  Simply leave your personal opinions out of the question.  You can ask for other folks' opinions or experience.  Keep your opinions to yourself when asking a question.  Few things are as irritating as a "question" that is simply a rant, complaint or blog-post in disguise.

Comment: @S.Lott I was just joking, but thanks I take your point, I do try to do this, I tend to find that often the best service SO provides me with is help in answering my own questions as I try to formulate them as posts, numerous times I come here looking for help and by the time I've composed what I want to ask something has clicked and I don't end up posting... right now I'm just looking for a good place to discuss a specific topic, but if SO is good for it that's great.

Comment: @panamack:  I'm not joking.  Some people find SO to be a place where they can attempt to promote their opinions through snarky questions.  Your question, for example, includes "a good TDD focussed place", which could be a claim that SO isn't good enough to meet your lofty standards.  "good" is often difficult to define, and sometimes a sign of a purely subjective and impossible-to-answer question.  It's easy to avoid.  Simply ask the question without any personal opinion.

Comment: @S.Lott from the FAQ "Avoid asking questions that are subjective, argumentative, or require extended discussion" hence the use of the phrase "a good place to discuss".  There was nothing really to be read between the lines.

Comment: @panamack: Sorry.  You're wrong.  Many people ask for a "good" X specifically meaning that they have an X which is not "good".  While the FAQ's suggest not doing this -- and it seems clear to you -- actual questions are not so well done.  Many people ask for a "good" editor or a "good" database or a "better" IDE without defining their terms.

Comment: @S.Lott, no I'm not wrong, the 'good' in this context is as opposed to the Google group which has only 3 posts in 2010 and seems to be littered with spam, my terms are defined in the body of my question.

Comment: @panamck: When it comes to "subjective", you said "There was nothing really to be read between the lines".  You're wrong.  It's clear **to you** and clear **for this question** but not to everyone for all questions.  You don't see anything subjective about your question.  However, many people do have problems with subjectivity and there is plenty of opportunity to read between the lines.  It is not crystal clear in general.  And the word "good" -- in general -- can be hard to interpret.  In this question, perhaps it's clear.  In general, however, it is not clear.

Comment: Have you ever thought about taking up a marshal arts course to release stress?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/testdrivendevelopment/ - they are very active and always open to discussion.

http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/extremeprogramming/ is another good one. Obviously TDD is only one of the practices of extreme programming so topics won't be limited to strictly TDD.

http://groups.google.com/group/software_craftsmanship - Another good one. Again not strictly limited to TDD.

If you're looking for discussions about a particular testing framework most have their own user forums. Here's a [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks) of frameworks for various languages.

Comment: +1 for providing links to active groups to answer what the OP asked and for suggesting discussions on specific frameworks, and for the link to various frameworks by language.

Answer (score 1):

There's an Agile Developer Skills Group that is fairly active. Obviously it has a larger focus than just TDD, but it might help:
http://groups.google.com/group/agile-developer-skills?pli=1

Answer (score 0):

Before/On/After somo Dojo/Kata sessions

So you can both discuss it subjectively and do some practice

Answer (score 0):

This might help : https://stackoverflow.com/